# how to filter multiple string in NsmutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nspredicate, nsmutabledictionary

Hi everyone in my projects i having the NSMutableArray containing a Number of Dictionary value,here i filtered by one string, but now i want to filter a multiple strings in this array,that is below is my Array Value

```
(
        {
        BusAC = "A/C";
        BusFare = 550;
        BusType = "Semi Sleeper";
        TravelsName = "ABC Travels";
    },
        {
        BusAC = "Non A/C";
        BusFare = 600;
        BusType = Seater;
        TravelsName = "Arulmigu Aandal Azahagar Madurai Express";
    },
        {
        BusAC = "A/C";
        BusFare = 1250;
        BusType = Sleeper;
        TravelsName = "GSP  Travels";
    },
        {
        BusAC = "Non A/C";
        BusFare = 350;
        BusType = "Semi Sleeper";
        TravelsName = "Madura  Travels";
    },
        {
        BusAC = "A/C";
        BusFare = 420;
        BusType = Seater;
        TravelsName = "MJT Travels";
    },
        {
        BusAC = "A/C";
        BusFare = 1500;
        BusType = Sleeper;
        TravelsName = "OPR Travels";
    },
        {
        BusAC = "Non A/C";
        BusFare = 730;
        BusType = Seater;
        TravelsName = "MJT Travels";
    }
)
```

in this i filtered by one string like Sleeper buses

```
NSPredicate *predicateStr1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"BusType",@"Sleeper"];
 NSMutableArray *filteredArray1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[totDictArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateStr1]];
```

then i filtered by two string like Sleeper & AC

```
NSPredicate * prediStr=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"BusType == %@ AND BusAC == %@",@"Sleeper",@"A/C"];
```

this also working good but now i want to filter like having array & string

```
String is A/C & Array value is (
    "ABC Travels",
    "GSP  Travels"
)
```

i tried this code 
here the arr is the Above mentioned array

```
 for (int i=0; i<arr.count; i++)
        {
            NSPredicate * prediStr=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TravelsName == %@ AND BusAC == %@",arr[i],@"A/C"];
            NSLog(@"prediStr %@",prediStr);
            NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[totDictArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:prediStr]];
                NSLog(@"filteredArray %@",filteredArray);
        }
```

help me..

**Updated**

```
(
        {
        Boarding =         (
            "CMBT Omini BS",
            CMBT,
            Vadapalani,
            "Ashok Nagar",
            Thambaram,
            Perungulathur,
            Vandalur
        );
        BusAC = "A/C";
        BusFare = 550;
        BusType = "Semi Sleeper";
        Dropping = "Trichy Bypass";
        TravelsName = "ABC Travels";
    },
        {
        Boarding =         (
            "CMBT Omini BS",
            CMBT,
            Vadapalani,
            "Ashok Nagar",
            Thambaram,
            Perungulathur,
            Vandalur
        );
        BusAC = "Non A/C";
        BusFare = 600;
        BusType = Seater;
        Dropping = "Chathram BS";
        TravelsName = "Arulmigu Aandal Azahagar Madurai Express";
    },
        {
        Boarding =         (
            "CMBT Omini BS",
            CMBT,
            Vadapalani,
            "Ashok Nagar",
            Thambaram,
            Perungulathur,
            Vandalur
        );
        BusAC = "A/C";
        BusFare = 1250;
        BusType = Sleeper;
        Dropping = "Thillai Nagar";
        TravelsName = "GSP  Travels";
    },
        {
        Boarding =         (            
            Thambaram,
            Perungulathur,
            Vandalur
        );
        BusAC = "Non A/C";
        BusFare = 350;
        BusType = "Semi Sleeper";
        Dropping = "Trichy Bypass";
        TravelsName = "Madura  Travels";
    },
        {
        Boarding =         (
            "CMBT Omini BS",
            CMBT,
            Vadapalani,
            "Ashok Nagar",
            Guindy,
            Velachery,
            Thambaram,
        );
        BusAC = "A/C";
        BusFare = 420;
        BusType = Seater;
        Dropping = "Court Campus";
        TravelsName = "MJT Travels";
    },
        {
        Boarding =         (
            "CMBT Omini BS",
            CMBT,
            Thambaram,
            Perungulathur,
            Vandalur
        );
        BusAC = "A/C";
        BusFare = 1500;
        BusType = Sleeper;
        Dropping = "Central BS";
        TravelsName = "OPR Travels";
    },
        {
        Boarding =         (
            "CMBT Omini BS",
            CMBT,
            Vadapalani,
            "Ashok Nagar",
            Thambaram,
        );
        BusAC = "Non A/C";
        BusFare = 730;
        BusType = Seater;
        Dropping = "Omini BS";
        TravelsName = "MJT Travels";
    }
)
```

in this array i've boarding also in this i want to Filter on the boarding array also that means BusAC is A/c & boarding is

```
 (Guindy,
            Velachery,
            Thambaram,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if a value is found in an array, you use the `IN` operator.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TravelsName IN %@", array];
```

Comment: thank you so much it working..i need to know more about NSPredicate.

Comment: Just wait until you finally understand SUBQUERY().  It opens up whole worlds :)

Comment: hi i have another doubt also in that i'm having boarding it's  a array value means how to i filter it

Comment: Ask in a separate question or modify this one.  I can't tell what you mean without an example.

Comment: The simplest thing to do is build a compound OR predicate, where each subpredicate uses `IN`.  I'm sure there's a better way, but I'm too busy to work it out at this time.

Comment: can u help me to filter that Boarding